# MATLAB Stateflow `ml` error (C vs MATLAB language)

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink, stateflow

I'm trying to use `ml` function in Stateflow. because of misunderstanding of my mistake I try example from help: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ug/calling-built-in-matlab-functions-and-accessing-workspace-data.html "Which ml Should I Use?" part.

[image]

And I get error:

> Subscript indices must be of a builtin numeric class. This index has
>   class 'char'.
>
> Transition '[i<5]{...,i,i);}'  "'A%d = rand(%d)'"

Debugger thinks that `ml` is a variable and try to add it into Model Explorer. It can't understand it correctly!

I read help with attention and only place that makes me lost in thoughts:

> **Caution**   Because MATLAB functions are not available in a target
>   environment, do not use the ml namespace operator and the ml function
>   if you plan to build a code generation target.

That's only my assumption, but maybe I'm using code generator that's why I have mistake? By the way I tried to Google about code generator, but can't get clearly opinion what is really it... 
My assumption again is: simulink build-in MATLAB function uses code generator so and Chart in Stateflow. Maybe I need to use some mex files or smth else to avoid using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two hours of trying and I got this:
code generation - it's, let's say, MATLAB language.
For using `ml` we need to set options of Chart to `C language'.
Like here: [image]

In left bottom corner we can see the Chart type: now it's `C`. Also you can see this in options.

So select `C` and `ml` starts to work.